# Algorithm for getting more precise time from server if request takes X milliseconds?

Tags: algorithm, timing

I have a server that returns current time. The requests itself takes some time because of the network latency, few milliseconds. Is there some statistical algorithm which would allow me to find actual time, something more advanced than "server_time - request_duration" or "server_time - request_duration / 2"?

```
Server returned time,request duration in milliseconds
2023-09-27T08:49:50.341,586
2023-09-27T08:49:52.997,80
2023-09-27T08:49:54.709,58
2023-09-27T08:49:55.700,59
2023-09-27T08:49:57.370,47
2023-09-27T08:49:58.376,56
2023-09-27T08:50:07.815,93
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol